# Cardinal numbers with countable cofinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

What does this assumption mean:

**Let $k$ be any cardinal number with uncountable cofinality**

Which cardinals have countable cofinality?

I know the definition of cofinality, but I'd like to see some examples of both countable and uncountable cofinality.

Comment: Do you know the definition of cofinality? Are you familiar with ordinals?

Comment: One non-trivial example is the cardinality of $\omega\cup P(\omega)\cup P(P(\omega))\cup \dots$.

Comment: yes, I know them. But not these types of cardinals. Could you please give me some more examples of both countable and uncountable cofinality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\{ \kappa_n : n < \omega \}$ be any increasing sequence of cardinals, then $\sup_n \kappa_n$ is a cardinal of countable cofinality.

For example, $\aleph_0 = \sup_n n$ is an infinite cardinal of countable cofinality, and $\aleph_{\omega} = \sup_n \aleph_n$ is another, but $\aleph_1$ is not (proving this is a standard exercise).

Answer (score 2):

$\aleph_\omega=\sup\{\aleph_n\mid n<\omega\}$ has countable cofinality.

More generally, if $\delta$ is a limit ordinal, then $\aleph_\delta$ has the same cofinality as $\delta$ (any cofinal sequence in $\delta$ can be translated to a cofinal sequence below $\aleph_\delta$). So any limit ordinal $\delta$ with countable cofinality would be mapped to a cardinal with a countable cofinality, $\aleph_\delta$.

Comment: I don't want to post another bad question here so I will just ask it in this comment: what is the cofinality of $\aleph_{\omega_{\omega_{\omega..._1}}}$, where this is $\aleph_1 + \aleph_{\omega_1} +...$ and the ellipsis covers $\aleph_0$ extensions, if that is indeed what this sums to? At first I thought its cofinality would be $\aleph_1$ but it seems you can get it by adding $\aleph_0$-many cardinals?

Comment: Since for a limit ordinal $\delta$ the cofinality of $\aleph_\delta$ is that of $\delta$, ask yourself what is the cofinality of $\omega_{\omega_{\omega..._1}}$, which I'm not 100% sure what it means (is it a sequence of length $\omega$ starting with $\omega_1$?). It looks like the limit of a sequence, if it's a countable sequence, then, well, it has a countable cofinality.

Comment: Hmm... I wish I knew how to phrase my question better  I guess, maybe... If the first fixed point of the aleph function is $\aleph_0 + \aleph_{\omega} +...$ = $\aleph_{\omega_{\omega_{\omega...}}}$, then what is  $\aleph_1 + \aleph_{\omega_1} +...$?

Comment: @KristianBerry: It's the same fixed point. You can interleave those sequences: $\aleph_0<\boldsymbol{\aleph_1}<\aleph_\omega<\boldsymbol{\aleph_{\omega_1}}<\dots$.

Comment: Thank you so much. This explains a lot... More than I can say right now. Btw, how are the immediate cardinal and ordinal successors to the FFP usually notated? Are they fixed points too?

Comment: I don't have access to any good opensource material on any of this, so thank you for bearing with me.

Comment: If $\Theta$ is the first fixed-point, then $\Theta^+$ is its cardinal successor and $\Theta+1$ is the ordinal successor. They are, of course, not fixed points, because fixed points are limit cardinals and neither is a limit cardinal.